# No Results showing from MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table named "repairs". Inside that table I have the following rows:

job_number (INT11) AUTO INCREMENT -> this is the number that the customer enters into the repair status form I am building...

Date | client_full_name | item_for_repair | tech_assigned | technician_notes | current_status

The whole thing is supposed to first check if the job number the customer enters into the form is in the database and show the status of that job number based on what's in the database. If the job number they enter does not exist in the database, or they enter it wrong, they are prompted with a No Record Found message...

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['btn_get_status'])) {
    // Connection code.
    $options = [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=ecemscoz_ecemsapp;charset=utf8mb4', 'ecemscoz_ecemsapp', 'C3m3t3ry!@', $options);

    // Prepared statement
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE job_number=?');
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['job_number']]);
    $exists = $stmt->fetchColumn(); // either 1 or null

    if ($exists) {
        echo "Status for $job_number is currently $current_status";
    } else {
        echo 'No Record Found';
    }
}
```

The issue I am now facing is that when I enter a number that's NOT in the databse, it returns the else{ statement of No Record Found.... PERFECT!

No Record Found Working As Expected:
[image: No Record Found Working As Expected]

But if I enter a job number that does really exist, it shows blank fields where job number and current status need to be.

Result is Empty:
[image: Result is Empty]

I am really struggling to understand what I am missing or where to implement it. Is my new PDO code an improvement or has it got worse with this try?

Comment: Where are $job_number and $current_status set?

Comment: am i supposed to add  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE job_number =:job_number , current_status=:cuurent_status'); 
  $stmt->bindParam(':job_number',$job_number,PDO::PARAM_STR); etc etc?

Comment: You should be getting undefined errors since the variables are not defined anywhere. Where do you expect they come from?

Comment: It looks like there are 2 different codes. Why did you include both?

Comment: No, what I understood is this line -> echo "Status for $job_number is currently $current_status"; is showing blacks in the variables, so, where are thos variables feed with a value?

Comment: The whole thing is supposed to first check if the job number the customer enters into the form is in the database and show the status of that job number based on whats in the database. If the job number they enter does not exist in the database, it needs to show No Record Found. Let me update my question with the table name and the contents of the "repairs" table that i need to get the data from

Comment: Then why do you need to check whether the row exists in the database separately? If you got the result then it means it exists.

Comment: Take a look to https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php, it will only fetch first column of first row. In your code you are saving in $exists the first column of the first row retrieved. Try https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php to get all columns, all rows and then print the job_number and status from that array

Comment: So which piece of code are we supposed to look at? Which one needs fixing? Why are there two?

Comment: ive edited again. Just the PHP code now showing needs fixing. I would like to know where i need to put the query that will allow $job_number and $current_status to show the actual values based on the job number they submit on the form. So if a customer enters their job number (example 5779) it will say "the current status for 5779 is Pending) for example. If the number doesnt exist, it needs to show "No Records Found" Technicians at my workshop have their own logins, so they change the status on a repair on their dashboard as they working on the laptop or desktop etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is in the query itself:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE job_number=?');
```

If that returns any result then it exists.
You should change the `$exists = $stmt->fetchColumn();` for `$exists = $stmt->fetch();`

With that exists will have two posible states: 1) an empty array if there is no job. 2) an array with all the rows and columns matching that job number.
Then you can do something like

```
if (empty($exists)) {
    echo 'No Record Found';
} else {
    echo "Status for {$exists['job_number']} is currently {$exists['current_status']}";
}
```

As @Dharman says you could reverse the if:

```
if ($exists) {
    echo "Status for {$exists['job_number']} is currently {$exists['current_status']}";
} else {
    echo 'No Record Found';
}
```

Comment: That `empty()` is useless there. Instead reverse the direction of the `if`

Comment: thrown in .repairstatusdev.php on line 53
[24-Jun-2021 21:43:09 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '";
' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in repairstatusdev.php on line 72

Comment: @masterofmatrix I fixed the mistake

Comment: works well... Your answer has helped me understand a lot more than i did when i started this project.... I reversed the if statement

if ($exists) {
        echo "Status for {$exists['job_number']} is currently {$exists['current_status']}";
      } else {
   echo 'No Record Found';
}